# Failed parsing 'srcset' -- <picture> in React -- Component for Responsive Images

Tags: image, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

Following this tutorial  [A Guide to Responsive Images with Ready-to-Use Templates](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-responsive-images-with-ready-to-use-templates-c400bd65c433)

I find the following problem to implement a component in react:

> Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown
>   descriptor
>
> Dropped srcset candidate "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.webp"

And it ends up loading only the image that is in src of the tag img

My react component is the following:

```
/**
 * Component to receive images and be responsive
 */
class RImage extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      lg_1x, 
      lg_2x, 
      md_1x, 
      md_2x, 
      sm_1x, 
      sm_2x,
      lg_1x_JPG, 
      md_1x_JPG, 
      sm_1x_JPG, 
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <picture>
        <source
          media="(min-width: 900px)"
          srcSet={`${lg_1x} 1x, ${lg_2x} 2x"`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
        <source
          media="(min-width: 601px)"
          srcSet={`${md_1x} 1x, ${md_2x} 2x"`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
        <source
          srcSet={`${sm_1x} 1x, ${sm_2x} 2x"`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
          <img  
            srcSet={`${sm_1x_JPG} 600w,
            ${md_1x_JPG} 900w,
            ${lg_1x_JPG} 1440w`}
            src={lg_1x_JPG} //This is the file that loads in the browser
            type="image/jpeg"
            alt="image description" 
          />  
        </picture>
    );
  }
}
```

Here I show how I am using it:

```
//Responsive Images
import lg_1x_JPG from '../../images/Programing/Programing-lg_1x.jpg';
import md_1x_JPG from '../../images/Programing/Programing-md_1x.jpg';
import sm_1x_JPG from '../../images/Programing/Programing-sm_1x.jpg';
//Only Chrome
import lg_1x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-lg_1x.webp';
import lg_2x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-lg_2x.webp';
import md_1x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-md_1x.webp';
import md_2x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-md_2x.webp';
import sm_1x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-sm_1x.webp';
import sm_2x from '../../images/Programing/Programing-sm_2x.webp';


class ImageClas extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <h1>Image</h1>
          <p>A beautiful Image</p>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
         <RImage
              lg_1x={lg_1x}
              lg_2x={lg_2x}
              md_1x={md_1x}
              md_2x={md_2x}
              sm_1x={sm_1x}
              sm_2x={sm_2x}
              lg_1x_JPG={lg_1x_JPG}
              md_1x_JPG={md_1x_JPG}
              sm_1x_JPG={sm_1x_JPG}
            />
          </div>
        </Grid>
       </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

I think the problem lies in how WepPack imports the image file because the console sends the `error Dropped srcset candidate "/static/media/anyFile.webp"`, this is a relative path and I'm not sure if srcSet needs an Absolute path.

How can I finish my component of Responsive Images? working in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code had a few more commas

```
       <source
          media="(min-width: 900px)"
          srcSet={`${lg_1x} 1x, ${lg_2x} 2x`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
        <source
          media="(min-width: 601px)"
          srcSet={`${md_1x} 1x, ${md_2x} 2x`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
        <source
          srcSet={`${sm_1x} 1x, ${sm_2x} 2x`}
          type="image/webp" 
        />
```

As I had already written the whole question I will leave it for two reasons, try to help someone who has a similar problem and the other is so that the component serves as a base for someone who is looking for responsive images